# How to get data from AWS Athena in EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am beginner in AWS.

My client has given me access to an EC2 instance, and has given me access to a few tables using Athena. The tables are in AWSDataCatalog. I don't have much information on the source of the table.

I just want to get some data from these queries in my EC2 instance.

I ran through the documentation of Athena and its API. But I am unable to find.

Will I be connecting to Athena service to get data or will I be connecting to the original data source and Athena is just an editor provided by AWS?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Athena is another service like S3 DynamoDB, etc. You can use an Amazon Athena API to retrieve data from it. For example, assume you want to write the code using AWS SDK for Java v2. You can retrieve data using this code.

```
package aws.example.athena;

//snippet-start:[athena.java2.StartQueryExample.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.AthenaClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.model.QueryExecutionContext;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.model.ResultConfiguration;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.model.StartQueryExecutionRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.model.StartQueryExecutionResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.model.AthenaException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.model.GetQueryExecutionRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.model.GetQueryExecutionResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.model.QueryExecutionState;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.model.GetQueryResultsRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.model.GetQueryResultsResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.model.ColumnInfo;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.model.Row;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.model.Datum;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.paginators.GetQueryResultsIterable;
import java.util.List;
//snippet-end:[athena.java2.StartQueryExample.import]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
//snippet-start:[athena.java2.StartQueryExample.main]
public class StartQueryExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        AthenaClient athenaClient = AthenaClient.builder()
            .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
            .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
            .build();

        String queryExecutionId = submitAthenaQuery(athenaClient);
        waitForQueryToComplete(athenaClient, queryExecutionId);
        processResultRows(athenaClient, queryExecutionId);
        athenaClient.close();
    }

    // Submits a sample query to Amazon Athena and returns the execution ID of the query.
    public static String submitAthenaQuery(AthenaClient athenaClient) {
        try {
            // The QueryExecutionContext allows us to set the database.
            QueryExecutionContext queryExecutionContext = QueryExecutionContext.builder()
                .database(ExampleConstants.ATHENA_DEFAULT_DATABASE)
                .build();

            // The result configuration specifies where the results of the query should go.
            ResultConfiguration resultConfiguration = ResultConfiguration.builder()
                .outputLocation(ExampleConstants.ATHENA_OUTPUT_BUCKET)
                .build();

            StartQueryExecutionRequest startQueryExecutionRequest = StartQueryExecutionRequest.builder()
                .queryString(ExampleConstants.ATHENA_SAMPLE_QUERY)
                .queryExecutionContext(queryExecutionContext)
                .resultConfiguration(resultConfiguration)
                .build();

            StartQueryExecutionResponse startQueryExecutionResponse = athenaClient.startQueryExecution(startQueryExecutionRequest);
            return startQueryExecutionResponse.queryExecutionId();

        } catch (AthenaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }

    // Wait for an Amazon Athena query to complete, fail or to be cancelled.
    public static void waitForQueryToComplete(AthenaClient athenaClient, String queryExecutionId) throws InterruptedException {
        GetQueryExecutionRequest getQueryExecutionRequest = GetQueryExecutionRequest.builder()
            .queryExecutionId(queryExecutionId)
            .build();

        GetQueryExecutionResponse getQueryExecutionResponse;
        boolean isQueryStillRunning = true;
        while (isQueryStillRunning) {
            getQueryExecutionResponse = athenaClient.getQueryExecution(getQueryExecutionRequest);
            String queryState = getQueryExecutionResponse.queryExecution().status().state().toString();
            if (queryState.equals(QueryExecutionState.FAILED.toString())) {
                throw new RuntimeException("The Amazon Athena query failed to run with error message: " + getQueryExecutionResponse
                        .queryExecution().status().stateChangeReason());
            } else if (queryState.equals(QueryExecutionState.CANCELLED.toString())) {
                throw new RuntimeException("The Amazon Athena query was cancelled.");
            } else if (queryState.equals(QueryExecutionState.SUCCEEDED.toString())) {
                isQueryStillRunning = false;
            } else {
                // Sleep an amount of time before retrying again.
                Thread.sleep(ExampleConstants.SLEEP_AMOUNT_IN_MS);
            }
            System.out.println("The current status is: " + queryState);
        }
    }

    // This code retrieves the results of a query
    public static void processResultRows(AthenaClient athenaClient, String queryExecutionId) {
        try {

            // Max Results can be set but if its not set,
            // it will choose the maximum page size.
            GetQueryResultsRequest getQueryResultsRequest = GetQueryResultsRequest.builder()
                .queryExecutionId(queryExecutionId)
                .build();

            GetQueryResultsIterable getQueryResultsResults = athenaClient.getQueryResultsPaginator(getQueryResultsRequest);
            for (GetQueryResultsResponse result : getQueryResultsResults) {
                List<ColumnInfo> columnInfoList = result.resultSet().resultSetMetadata().columnInfo();
                List<Row> results = result.resultSet().rows();
                processRow(results, columnInfoList);
            }

        } catch (AthenaException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           System.exit(1);
       }
    }

    private static void processRow(List<Row> row, List<ColumnInfo> columnInfoList) {
        for (Row myRow : row) {
            List<Datum> allData = myRow.data();
            for (Datum data : allData) {
                System.out.println("The value of the column is "+data.varCharValue());
            }
        }
    }
    //snippet-end:[athena.java2.StartQueryExample.main]
}
```

You can find this example and others in AWS Github:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/athena